# Draw a line perpendicular to an arc at a particular point with Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to draw a line perpendicular to an arc at a particular point. I'm using `path.arcTo` to draw the arc. I have to say, I already managed to do something similar, by drawing the arc, and then increase the radius and tell flutter to draw another arc, but with an invalid sweepAngle, in that way flutter draws the perpendicular line I want. However, this at the beginning worked, but later on gave me some bugs. I'm sharing with you the initial code that I'm using. I'd like to know if there is a specific method or way to achieve what the first image shows, after drawing the arc:

[image]

```
Offset center = Offset(screenSize.width / 2, screenSize.height / 2);
double degreesToRadians(double degrees) => degrees * (math.pi / 180);

  path.arcTo(
      Rect.fromCircle(center: center, radius: 150),
      degreesToRadians(180),
      degreesToRadians(135),
      true);
```

I'm working directly with degrees. Therefore the function `degreesToRadians`.

My current result is just this:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1) use math 2) use `PathMetric`

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying that out. Just need to figure out point number one.

Comment: Right now I'm looking for the method of a PathMetric object to obtain the offset of the end of the arc.

Comment: In other words, the position x and y.

Comment: this is the last point on the arc - so it is equal to its length

Comment: `pm.getTangentForOffset(pm.length)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228177/discussion-between-ivan-yoed-and-pskink).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, what I did was to declare `final outerRadiusPoint` (the point where I wanted to take my line to go to) by establishing a `sizeToIncrease` for the radius, obtaining cosine of `startingAngle` and sine of `startingAngle`, adding `center.dx` and `center.dy` respectively and multiplying each by the size we want our new radius to be.

After that, we draw our arc with `path.arcTo`. Then we obtain the offset of the end of the arc with `PathMetrics` and `PathMetric`. With that we are now able to move the path to that position and start drawing again to the `Offset` of `outerRadiusPoint`.

```
    final outerRadiusPoint = new Point(
        (sizeForRadius + sizeToIncrease) * cos(degreesToRadians(startingAngle)) + center.dx,
        (sizeForRadius + sizeToIncrease) * sin(degreesToRadians(startingAngle)) + center.dy);

    path.arcTo(
        Rect.fromCircle(center: center, radius: sizeForRadius),
        degreesToRadians(initialPoint),
        degreesToRadians(buttonArcLength),
        true);

    PathMetrics pms = path.computeMetrics();
    PathMetric pm = pms.last;
    Offset pmoffset = pm.getTangentForOffset(pm.length).position;
    
      path.lineTo(outerRadiusPoint.x, outerRadiusPoint.y);
      path.moveTo(pmoffset.dx, pmoffset.dy);
```